# Obtain just the "id" of the row being deleted from jqgrid table

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am new to jQuery and jqGrid tables. I am trying to find just the `id` of the row being deleted from the jqGrid table. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid don't hold somewhere the ids of deleted rows. If your code calls *explicitly* methods like `delRowData` or `delGridRow` then you can save the ids of the rows which will be deleted in an array.

If you just use `navGrid`, `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"` and you don't call `delRowData` or `delGridRow` *directly, then you can use `beforeSubmit` callback of `delGridRow` to get the information about the ids of deleting rows *before* the rows will be deleted. Don't forget to return `[true]` from `beforeSubmit` to allow deleting.